# My alarm didn't go off this morning!

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, 2.1-eclair, alarm

I set an alarm up and I can see the alarm symbol at the top in the notification bar. However, the alarm didn't go off this morning! Thankfully I'm still in the crossover where my old phone is still in use.

Does the phone have to remain switched on at all times in order for alarms to function?

It's a Galaxy S running 2.1 *still, because apparently we're still waiting for Orange to decide how much bloat they want to pack 2.2 with before release*.

Comment: The alarm clock is the reason I still use an old skool Nokia phone. It even works when the phone is switched off. Try doing *that* with Android.

Comment: Did you accidentally have the volume turned down?

Comment: This question on the old ForceClose site has some of the background on the issue of alarms working while a phone's switched off http://www.forceclose.com/questions/776/can-alarms-go-off-when-the-device-is-off and unfortunately every Android device I've owned, the alarm only works when the device is switched on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use any task killer? Make sure you don't kill the "Clock" apps.

In fact, don't use a task killer at all, they're harmful to Android.

Comment: That was probably it - I had killed some apps with the task killer and the clock must've gone as a result. Out of interest, why is the task killer harmful?

Comment: @bcmcfc - Here's an article that will explain task killers for you: http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the phone has to remain switched on for the Alarm to work.

Comment: True, on every Android phone I've had so far (from both HTC and Samsung) the alarm doesn't work if the phone's not switched on.

Comment: That's really handy to know - I've been using Nokias for a number of years and will have to make sure I don't forget, turn the phone off and oversleep as a result of the switch to Android.

Comment: Yeah, I learned about this too, the hard way. :( Ericsson rings the bell even when it's off. Well eff you samsung...