# How to make my alarm as stable as a server?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, updates, alarm

I have HTC Desire with original Android 2.2 (kernel 2.6.32.15-gf5a401c) with HTC Sence. I have not installed any task killers.

Now I have a stock alarm clock application.

Yesterday evening I set my alarm for 6:30am, but got up at 10 being 2h+ late for my work.
When I took my phone, I noticed 3 things

- it was showing a message like "Adobe Flash Player cannot be installed without internet connection";
- second thing I noted is "Low on space" notification --- common problem for HTC Desire;
- my alarm was silently asking me if I want to snooze or dismiss it.

**I want**

- to have an alarm clock on my phone as stable as my bicycle, i.e. which

  - works as expected;
  - does not turn off automatically after 1, 5, 10 or 100500 minutes;
  - does not stop working in case of update or any other event (except airplane mode);
- to have Android update like Debian Squeeze, i.e. not to update automatically (at least if it causes problems), but gently suggest to install only security critical updates and to give any other suggestions only by special request;
- some logging for my alarm to "debug" problems with waking up.

In the list above I mention not only the alarm, but the whole system (Android update), because I think that tuning off the system can help to stabilize my alarm. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Question**

- What can be done to make my system and, importantly, my alarm, very stable?
- What is the most stable alarm clock app?
- Is there any way to make it even more stable (for instance, turn off updates to stick with a stable version)?

**What is done**

I have found the following relevant threads:

- "[Is there an alarm clock event log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2284/is-there-an-alarm-clock-event-log)" has no satisfactory answer;
- "[Which Alarm clock app do you use to wake up in the morning?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/581/best-alarm-clock-on-android)" suggests [Smart Alarm Clock](http://www.smart-alarm-clock.com/) and [Gentle Alarm](http://m.mobitobi.com/en/android/gentlealarm.php), [a similar thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10474/gentle-alarm-3-1-x-replacement-alternative) suggests Alarm Clock Xtreme ([ad-supported](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free) or [paid ($2)](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme)); I do not have any information on stability of these;
- the following threads about alarm clock incidents: [[1]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/my-alarm-didnt-go-off-this-morning), [[2]](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12496/notification-snoozes-alarm);
- "[disable update notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5671/disable-application-update-notification)" - done.

**Future**

Probably at some point I will reinstall Android with a question of solving [low internal memory problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help) in mind. So if there are some solutions for a different version of Android (say 2.3) or advice for installation to make my system and alarm stable I would like to know them.

**Update**
As roxan pointed out, probably alarm rings just for a few minutes. If it is so, I would like to turn off this feature or set this time to something big (2 hours or more).

Comment: I got Gentle Alarm through Amazon, and it couldn't be shut off without an internet connection due to Amazon's DRM.  Very annoying.  I've never had a problem with the stock Alarm app on my SGS.  That said, if you want a stable alarm you should get a dedicated one where less can go wrong.

Comment: It's ironic. We all have highly sophisticated multi-function super-duper smartphones. But still we need an cheap old-fashioned alarm clock to get reliable up in the morning. :-D

Comment: Honestly speaking, there are a lot of Android apps, which potentially can improve my daily life, but because of stability issues I use them much more rarely than I could. To name a few, Evernote (needs internet for search), Google Maps (sometimes it is too slow, often needs internet), Google Voice (needs internet), Swype (often doesn't work without update). I have internet on my phone but sometimes it doesn't work. I'll likely buy a dedicated alarm soon, but it's not a universal solution. I'd like to apply reasonable effort, if it helps to use useful features of the phone I have.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Desire and this has never/ever happened to me under any circumstances. Alarm would not work if you had killed it but you have clearly specified you don't have any task killer.

As you said there is Snooze/Dismiss screen, the alarm indeed went on. Are you sure you didn't miss when the alarm rang at the correct time? Or are you sure the volume is loud enough?

Comment: Both ring volume and alarm volume were set to maximum. I don't know if it rang or not, I just know, that it was not ringing at the moment I waked up. Thus I cannot exclude for sure possibility that it rang for 1, 5, 10 or 30 minutes. I don't know if turns on automatically or not. I should, probably, make an experiment: turn on alarm, and record the sound (so I will know its duration).

Comment: Usually I wake up few minutes before my Alarm goes on and it rings when I'm in toilet. It usually is ringing when I come back but sometimes if I take too long in the toilet, the alarm would be in stage as you mentioned with "Snooze/Dismiss" on screen.